# Create one ViewModel per fragment or create one static viewModel in activity? which one is true

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-livedata

My app has an `activity` on which many `fragments` are placed for different pages.

Some fragments have a `recyclerView` that data given via a `viewModel`.

Now, I would first create an instance of the `viewModel` in each `fragment` and put the data in the `recyclerView` using observer and `LiveData`, but this caused `LiveData` observer is being triggered two times.

After that, the idea came to me to create a static instance of the `viewModel` in the `activity` class to solve this problem and use it in different `fragments`. It worked, and `LiveData` observer triggered once.

Now my question is, is it right to use a static instance of `viewModel` in `MainActivity` (and use it from fragments)?

If not, then what should I do to solve the problem(Trigger the observer twice)?

Comment: why make it static ? just use the activity context in the fragment when making the VM, that's what the official documentation would also tell you

Comment: Yes, I used activity context at first, but found the problem of triggering the LiveData observer twice

Comment: There is no scenario in which a static instance of a ViewModel is correct